# Retrofit. Неизвестный тип поля

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Не могу понять, как обработать такие ответы от сервера:

```
{ "id":1 "value":false }
{ "id":1 "value":"text"}
{ "id":1 "value":12345 }
```

Эти ответы могут быть от одного и того же метода.
Как в этом случае я должен создать класс модели, при условии, что эта модель должна будет реализовать интерфейс Parcelabe?

Язык - Kotlin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы привели все возможные типы данных в поле, то можно указывать тип для `value` как `String`. После надо будет вручную проверять на этапе исполнения в какой тип можно распарсить значение.

Если там может быть ещё и массив - то тип должен быть `Any`.

А самое правильное решение - объяснить людям, пишущим сервер, что на вашей стороне - статически типизируемый язык и вы не можете комфортно парсить такие структуры данных в отличие от `php`, `js`, `python`. Чтобы вам было комфортно на бэке должны добавить поле в ответ, в коем будет содержаться тип значения `value` - тогда вы сможете написать адаптер для парсинга JSON который будет в зависимости от значения парсить в одну или другую модель данных.